# Rich:ExtendedDataTable using frozenColumns makes non frozen columns disappear

Tags: richfaces

I am trying to freeze columns in *rich:extendedDataTable* using `frozenColumns` attribute. 
When I am not using this attribute every column is visible like it's supposed to be in a normal case, but when I use this attribute (`frozenColumns="2"`) only those 2 frozen columns are showing and other non frozen columns are not showing at all, not even the scrollbar. I am using *rich:columns* for this extended datatable.

Comment: It can be a number of things, can you share some code?

Comment: thanks for your response Makhiel. Of course i will put my piece of code in here as soon as i get back to the office. Cheers man.    I changed my rich extendeddatatable to a simple prototype rich extendeddatatable as shown in the documentation just to test it. but it was showing the same thing. So i am wondering it could be because of the panelGroup which wraps it or smth in which it is contained or smth like that. I will let you know asap.Cheers Makhiel.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I finally managed to sort it out. the problem was the div in which the extendeddatattable was contained. for that div i had given styling class which was ' .searchContent table { width:1000px'} '

so basically when we use frozenColumn attribute, in html format it spilts the table into two tables with frozencolumns in one and non frozen columns in other. So the given 1000px styling width was assigned to the first table which has frozen columns and 1000px is actually the width of its parent container which is another div. so it only shows the first table making the second table, which has the non frozen columns and scroll stuffs, disappear.

I removed that styling class and got it working. Cheers.